# Unwanted spacing between android viewgroups added programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding a `RelativeLayout` in a `FrameLayout` ( added in xml ) and I attach a `LinearLayout` in this RelativeLayout.

The problem is I get an unwanted left/right spacing/padding between the RelativeLayout and its child LinearLayout as you can see here from the uiautomator dump.
The weird thing is that spacing is **always** 11 pixels from each side tested on emulator N5, N4, N7 images and Moto G and N4 devices. 
Thank you

[image]

The code is :

```
       rlBottomBarContainer = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rlBottomBarContainer.setId(R.id.bottomBarContainer);
    rlBottomBarContainer.setClipToPadding(false);
    rlBottomBarContainer.setClipChildren(false);
    rlBottomBarContainer.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bara));

    int topMargin = whiteTowerContainerHeight /2 + tower_height/2 + 100;
    int containerHeight = whiteTowerContainerHeight - topMargin;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
             containerHeight);
    containerParams.topMargin = topMargin;

    rlBottomBarContainer.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
    frameLayoutRoot.addView(rlBottomBarContainer);     // parentLayout

    llBottomBarContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    llBottomBarContainer.setId(R.id.upper_bottombar_ID);
    llBottomBarContainer.setClipChildren(false);
    llBottomBarContainer.setClipToPadding(false);
    llBottomBarContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
    llBottomBarContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bottomBarParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
             getBottomBarTextSize());

    llBottomBarContainer.setLayoutParams(bottomBarParams);
    rlBottomBarContainer.addView(llBottomBarContainer);
```

As you can see from the code the `LinearLayout` is added with match_parent for the width. RelativeLayout width is from 0 to 720px but LinearLayout is from 11 to 709pixels.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I do not understand why you use a FrameLayout and you do not use directly the RelativeLayout as your parent layout.

The error I see on your code is that you set a FrameLayout.LayoutParams to your RelativeLayout and a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams to your LinearLayout.
Probably this is why you get some extra spacing.

I would suggest that you do not create your layouts programmatically, but rather do it on xml and then if you need the layout objects on java you can get them with the findViewById(int id) method

Comment: Afaik the child view ( or ViewGroup ) inherits its layout params from the parent so they should be the same type as parent.

I have to create them programmatically cause  some of their properties aren't known from the beginning. 

Lastly I use a FrameLayout cause I attach other views to it and not just the RelativeLayout.  
Overall thank you for the try :)

Comment: You seem to be right about the layout params. I always use addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) instead of setting the layoutParams and then using addView (View child).

Comment: Try to addRule (ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_LEFT) to your RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. This might work

Comment: Well what seems to works is explicitly setting padding to zero for the RelativeLayout : `rlBottomBarContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);` . Still  I don't know what is the cause of this problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: :D
probably the default padding is not set to 0. Glad to be of help even if I did not really find the solution. Happy coding!